# Wget error: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized Authorization failed

Tags: linux, curl, wget

So i have to download a whole webpage for worst case scenario if our network collapses. But with Wget I only get Error 401 unauthorized. I suspect kerberos.

I've tried curl, at first it only showed index code then I added --output and it only downloads index page. But only index beacause after that the site is password protected.

```
 wget --header="Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --recursive --wait=5 --level=2 --execute="robots = off" --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains my.domain --no-parent https://webpage.internal
```

and curl

```
curl --anyauth --negotiate -u admin https://webpage.internal --output index.html
```

Is there any way to use curl for whole website, or is there a simple fix for my wget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it myself. Just needed to change:

```
-header="Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

to

```
-header="Authorization: OAuth XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

and it started to clone.

Edit: did not solve.

Comment: atleast at this moment i thougth i solved it. now it downloads index page some css and some language packages but nothing else. If i try to move forward from lindex page there's nothig there. i only can move to login page. so does it mean i don't have authorization to copy after that?